# A question in complex analysis on an entire function bounded in Unit disc

Tags: complex-analysis

I am completely stumped at a question asked in masters entrance .

> Let $h: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ be an analytic function such that $h(0)=0$ , $h\left(\dfrac 12\right)=5$ and $\vert h(z)\vert < 10$ for $\vert z\vert<1$. Then which of the following is/are true:
>
> 1. The set $\left\lbrace z:\vert h(z)\vert=5\right\rbrace$ is unbounded by Maximum Principle.
> 2. the set $\left\lbrace z:\vert h'(z)\vert=5\right\rbrace$ is a circle of strictly positive radius.
> 3. $h(1)=10$.
> 4. Regardeless of what $h'$ is, $h"$ is identically zero.

Unfortunately, despite doing a course on complex analysis, I have no idea how this problem can be approached.

So, I am Just asking for hints. No complete solutions are needed as I understand It will Take a lot of time.

Comment: Divide h by 10 then we get a holomorphic function mapping the unit disc to the unit disc.

Comment: Looks like (3) is the only plausible answer with $h(z)=10z$ an example of an analytic function that satisfies the hypotheses.

Comment: @Yannic are you familar with Scwarz Lemma?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can use Schwarz Lemma to determine h consider $$ f(z) = \frac{h(z)}{10} $$ clearly f is analytic and by assumption $ f(0) = 0$ and $ |f(z)| < 1 $ when $|z| < 1 $ also by assumption $ f(\frac{1}{2}) = \frac{1}{2} $ using Schwarz lemma we can deduce $ |f(z)| \leq |z| $ with equality iff $ f(z) = cz $ where c is a constant of absolute value one however by assumption $ f(\frac{1}{2}) = \frac{1}{2} $ so using Schwarz lemma and the assumptions we see that $ h(z) = 10z $ and thus 3 and 4 are correct while 1 and 2 are false

Comment: Very nice! ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$